# ElasticSearch aggregations for all pages

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, aggregation

I use `size` and `from` keywords for pagination across ElasticSearch results and each page change requires another search query to be executed.

I would like to compute facets with the `aggregations` feature, however aggregations are computed only based on the results constrained by `size` and `from` keywords e.g. when I ask for records 20-30 from the list, the aggregations are computed **only** on these 10 records that are returned. And I would like of course to have global facets computed on all the matching records that do not change while I switch the pages.

Any ideas how to do it apart from performing an additional global (uncostrained by `size` and `from`) search?

Comment: That's not the behavior that I see. Which version of Elasticsearch are you using? Also, could you post some example documents and queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregations are computed on all documents that match `"query"`. The scope of aggregations has nothing to do with `"size"` and `"from"` values.